# Result consisted of more than one row Error 1172 MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, stored-procedures, mysql-error

Hello im having a hard time with this stored procedure. I'm getting the error:
Result consisted of more than one row.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dss`.`COSTRET` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`dwadmin`@`192.168.%.%` PROCEDURE `COSTRET`( TDATE DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE ls_id VARCHAR(8);
    DECLARE ld_cost DECIMAL(10,4);
      DECLARE ld_retail DECIMAL(10,4);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `prod_performance` WHERE `psc_week` = TDATE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

  -- Get the Cost
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prod_itemcost`
    SELECT DISTINCTROW `itemcode` ID, `mlist` COST
    FROM (SELECT `itemcode`, `pceffdate`, `mlist`
        FROM `purchcost` a
        where `pceffdate` = (SELECT MAX(z.`pceffdate`) FROM `purchcost` z WHERE z.`itemcode` = a.`itemcode`
        AND z.`pceffdate` <= TDATE)) tb
    ORDER BY `itemcode`;

    OPEN cur1;
    REPEAT
      FETCH cur1 INTO ls_id;
      IF NOT done THEN
            SELECT DISTINCTROW `cost` INTO ld_cost FROM `prod_itemcost` WHERE id = ls_id;

        UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY `prod_performance` SET `current_cost` = ld_cost WHERE `psc_week` = TDATE and `id` = ls_id;
      END IF;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;
    CLOSE cur1;

   -- Destroy Temporary Tables
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLES IF EXISTS `prod_itemcost`;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Any solutions and recommendations are much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this question [MySQL Error 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row][1]

Thank you.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507993/mysql-error-1172-result-consisted-of-more-than-one-row

Answer (score 11):

I'd say the problem is here :

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW `cost` INTO ld_cost FROM `prod_itemcost` WHERE id = ls_id;
```

and caused by this returning more than one row.
How you solve it depends on your requirements. Does the existence of multiple rows imply the database is in need of some cleaning, for example? Or should you be taking the first value of 'cost', or perhaps the sum of all 'cost' for id = ls_id?

Edit :

Your INTO clause is attempting to write multiple rows to a single variable. Looking at your SQL, I'd say the underlying problem is that your initial query to pull back just the latest cost for each ID is being hamstrung by duplicates of pceffdate. If this is the case, this SQL :

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW `itemcode` ID, `mlist` COST
    FROM (SELECT `itemcode`, `pceffdate`, `mlist`
        FROM `purchcost` a
        where `pceffdate` = (SELECT MAX(z.`pceffdate`) FROM `purchcost` z WHERE z.`itemcode` = a.`itemcode`
        AND z.`pceffdate` <= TDATE)) tb
```

will return more rows than just this :

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW `itemcode` ID
    FROM (SELECT `itemcode`, `pceffdate`, `mlist`
        FROM `purchcost` a
        where `pceffdate` = (SELECT MAX(z.`pceffdate`) FROM `purchcost` z WHERE z.`itemcode` = a.`itemcode`
        AND z.`pceffdate` <= TDATE)) tb
```

Comment: it already has a DISTINCTROW so it will just return only 1 right? can you recommend a workaround?

Comment: That's not what DISTINCTROW does (which incidentally is synonymous with DISTINCT). If you have multiple different values for cost for each id, DISTINCT/DISTINCTROW will return multiple rows. DISTINCT/DISTINCTROW merely means you won't have duplicate rows. So, for example, if you have 3 rows with values of 50, 50 and 100, DISTINCT/DISTINCTROW will return 2 rows (one with 50 and one of 100).

Comment: umm so i should remove the DISTINCTROW from that line? . i removed the DISTINCTROW thing on my select staement and it still gives the same error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW `itemcode` ID, `mlist` COST
```

could store multiple costs against each ID, and so

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW `cost` INTO ld_cost FROM `prod_itemcost` WHERE id = ls_id;
```

could return multiple rows for each id.

For example, if purchcost contained the following:

```
itemcode   mlist   pceffdate
1          10.99   10-apr-2009
1          11.99   10-apr-2009
1           9.99   09-apr-2009
```

Then temporary table prod_itemcost would contain:

```
itemcode   mlist
1          10.99
1          11.99
```

These both being values that were in effect on the most recent pceffdate for that itemcode.

This would then cause a problem with selecting mlist into ld_cost for itemcode 1 because there are two matching values, and the scalar ld_cost can only hold one.

You really need to look at the data in purchcost.  If it is possible for 1 item to have more than one entry with different mlist values for the same date/datetime, then you need to decide how that should be handled.  Perhaps take the highest value, or the lowest value, or any value.  Or perhaps this is an error in the data.

Comment: uhmm im a little confused. what i need in the prod_itemcost temporary table is to get all the latest prices per product.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
SELECT MAX(z.`pceffdate`) FROM `purchcost` z WHERE z.`itemcode` = a.`itemcode`
    AND z.`pceffdate` <= TDATE
```

has got to be the problem.  It must be returning more than 1 row.  So, the DBMS is trying to set multiple values to the same thing, which of course it cannot do.

Do you need something else in your WHERE clause there?

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility, that is your parameter "TDATE" same as table field name in uppercase or lowercase or mixed. such as 'tdate', 'tDate', 'TDATE'.

so you should check that. I hit this before.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting an array in a variable instead of a single value that's why its problem occurs.

Like:

```
    DECLARE name varchar;

    select f_name into name from student;
```

here name will accept only single name instead of multiple name;

Comment: In that case how to solve this problem, if I want to return multiple rows from the procedure?

Comment: Prasanna ...........you can use cursor for this situation.

Like : DECLARE curColumn CURSOR FOR SELECT colname FROM pbx_pack_menu WHERE id NOT IN (7,8,9,11,14,87,118,119);

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row

Because I tried to store multiple row's `name` column values into `@result` which is [a user-defined session variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM person;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | David |
+----+-------+
...
mysql> SELECT name INTO @result FROM person; -- Error
```

But, I could store only one row's `name` column value into `@result` without error as shown below:

```sql
mysql> SELECT name INTO @result FROM person WHERE id = 1;
...
mysql> SELECT @result;  
+---------+
| @result |
+---------+
| John    |
+---------+
```