# MySQL Error 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm getting this error from MySQL when running a query inside a stored procedure:

> Error Code: 1172
>   Result consisted of more than one row

I understand the error: I'm doing a `SELECT (...) INTO (var list)`, and thus the query is required to return a single row. When I use `LIMIT 1` or `SELECT DISTINCT`, the error goes away.

However: when I run the original query manually (without `LIMIT` or `DISTINCT`), **it does return a single row**. So I'm suspecting I may have bumped into a MySQL bug. Does anyone know what could be happening?

**EDIT**

I'm posting the SQL as requested. Everything that starts with an underscore is a variable declared earlier inside the procedure. When I test it, I'm replacing `_cd_pai_vc` with the ID for the record that is causing the problem.

```
SELECT  a.valor,    IFNULL(p.valor, 0), fn_cd2alias(ra.cd_registro),    fn_cd2alias(IFNULL(p.valor,0))
INTO    _valor,     _cd_pai_vc,         _alias_verbete,                 _alias_pai
FROM dados_registros ra
    INNER JOIN dados_varchar255 a
    ON a.cd_registro = ra.cd_registro
        AND a.fl_excluido = 0
        AND a.alias = 'vc-verbetes-termo'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dados_registros rp
        INNER JOIN dados_int p
        ON p.cd_registro = rp.cd_registro
            AND p.fl_excluido = 0
            AND p.alias = 'vc-remissoes-termo referenciado'
        INNER JOIN dados_int pt
        ON pt.cd_registro = rp.cd_registro
            AND pt.fl_excluido = 0
            AND pt.alias = 'vc-remissoes-tipo remissao'
            AND fn_cd2alias(pt.valor) = 'hierarquica'
    ON ra.cd_registro = rp.cd_entidade
        AND rp.fl_excluido = 0
        AND fn_cd2alias(rp.cd_modulo) = 'vc-remissoes'
WHERE ra.cd_registro = _cd_pai_vc 
    AND ra.fl_excluido = 0;
```

Comment: @EugenRieck Added the SQL. I know the joins could cause extra rows to be fetched, but, as I stated in the question, when I test with an actual ID instead of `_cd_pai_vc` (and comment out the `INTO` part), I only get a single row.

Comment: Looks cery much like _cd_pai_vc has the wrong value: Just for testing, in the stored procedure replace it with the constant that gives only a single row when run manually and see if the error persists.

Comment: @EugenRieck: The query is actually inside a loop on the procedure. It's traversing a tree upwards, and `_cd_pai_id` is redefined to the current parent_id on each iteration. I tried what you suggested anyway, replacing the var with each parent_id involved, one at a time, and I don't get any errors. How come? When I `SELECT` the current value of the variable for debugging, it shows the exact same values I tried as constants, but then I get the error.

Comment: Change the code to either return the multiple rows, or to insert them somewhere. That may give you a hint why it is happening. It is probably not a MySQL bug.

Comment: @ErikEkman, done that. I had to repeat the query, because removing the INTO would put me in an endless loop. After 4 iterations, the loop ended, and there were 4 rows on my temp table, as expected, and no duplicates (the problem must be a duplicate, since DISTINCT solves it).

Comment: @bfavaretto I think I have the same issue. What version of MySQL are you using? Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @IamJohnGalt I gave up understanding the cause, and just added DISTINCT to the query. If I revisit it some day, I'll post news here.

Comment: Having this EXACT same issue. Commenting out the INSERT INTO and just having a select, I can see only 1 row is being returned. Adding LIMIT 1 STILL gives the error. Free for a reason!

Answer (score 5):

I had the similiar issue and when I put **table alias** it worked like a charm.

```
SELECT t.tax_amount,t.tax_percentage FROM nepse_tax t
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and found it went away when I used both table name and column name in select statements, even simple ones.

Answer (score 2):

The issue i had was IN parameter and the column name both were same so altered IN parameter name and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same error in mysql.

**MySQL Error 1172 - Result consisted of more than one row**

Then I saw the question:

[mysql stored procedure error (1172, 'Result consisted of more than one row')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19830053/mysql-stored-procedure-error-1172-result-consisted-of-more-than-one-row)

But it was not I meant to ask. `LIMIT 1;`-wasn't up to my expectation. It will just return the first row for all the case.

Then I started looking at this one deeply and now I got the solution.

This case happend because the code for stored procedure returns multiple rows and that was because I had many `extra spaces and tab characters` in my code[the code I wrote for stored procedure] and when I removed them with just one/two appropriate tab chars- it was just like a **flying machine**.

I don't know if it is the same case that you are experienced with. Anyway give a try.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution by Nava Bogatee worked like a charm,
below is a part of the procedure

```
select attendance
into brb
from Stud
where Rno like rno;
```

This didn't work I have no idea why.
Then I changed this to

```
select t.attendance
into brb
from Stud t
where t.Rno like rno;
```

and it worked.
I guess due to some reason the Rno column is returning all the values in the table, that is why the multiple row error.