# mysql stored procedure error (1172, 'Result consisted of more than one row')

Tags: mysql, django, stored-procedures

When trying to run the following stored procedure from django, I get an OperationError (1172, 'Result consisted of more than one row') Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdatePrices`(IN storeId int, IN bottleSize VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE amount DECIMAL(10,2); DECLARE isCustom INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE changeType VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'State'; DECLARE updateType INT DEFAULT 0;

        IF bottleSize = '1000 Ml' THEN
            SELECT S1000IncreaseChoices INTO changeType FROM store_store WHERE StoreID = storeId;

            IF changeType = 'State' THEN
                SELECT updateType = 0;
            END IF;

            IF changeType = 'Flat' THEN
                SELECT S1000IncreaseAmount INTO amount FROM store_store WHERE StoreID = storeId;
                SELECT updateType = 1;
            END IF;


            IF changeType = 'Percent' THEN
                SELECT 1 - S1000IncreaseAmount/100 INTO amount FROM store_store WHERE StoreID = storeId;
                SELECT updateType = 2;
            END IF;
        END IF;

        IF updateType = 0 THEN
            update store_storeliquor SL 
            inner join liquor_liquor LL
            on liquorID_id = id
            set StorePrice = ShelfPrice
            where BottleSize = bottleSize
            and storeID_id = storeId
            and custom = 0;
        END IF;

        IF updateType = 1 THEN
            update store_storeliquor SL 
            inner join liquor_liquor LL
            on liquorID_id = id
            set StorePrice = OffPremisePrice + amount
            where BottleSize = bottleSize
            and storeID_id = storeId
            and custom = 0;
        END IF;

        IF updateType = 1 THEN
            update store_storeliquor SL 
            inner join liquor_liquor LL
            on liquorID_id = id
            set StorePrice = OffPremisePrice / amount
            where BottleSize = bottleSize
            and storeID_id = storeId
            and custom = 0;
        END IF;



END
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but I initiate the stored procedure like so:

```
def priceupdate(request, store_id):

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc("UpdatePrices", (store_id, '1000 ML'))
    cursor.close()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your SELECT...INTO queries give result sets with more then one record. The WHERE filters are incorrect - they compare two the same values `StoreID = storeId`. Rename **IN storeId int** parementer to another name. For example - **IN storeId_param int**

The query will be like this -

```
SELECT S1000IncreaseChoices INTO changeType FROM store_store WHERE StoreID = storeId_param;
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Now I gotta figure out why the code isn't doing what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bug and you need to apply something like that:

```
SELECT id,data INTO x,y FROM test.t1 LIMIT 1;
```